# Push Notification of update in Article

Tags: android, push-notification

I have converted Article Website to Android App using WebView.

How to use push notification for any update of Article in Android?

Comment: `Waiting for Answers.` Waiting for a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many platforms available for push notification in android. you can use [Firebase Push notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) OR [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) Push notification. [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) provides an admin panel for sending push notification so it is easy to use.

Comment: Thank You for help..Sir can you guide me a source from where i can implement OneSignal Easily?

Comment: here you can find complete documentation for integrating Onesignal : https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/mobile-sdk-setup